# project to create a lighter wall

Tags: mobile-robot, control, motor, sensors

We are working in a project to help blind people cross the street alone .so ,Can I create a Virtual reality wall or a holographic 3d one that is visible in the Street and in all day times ?? ( morning ..)I mean is it doable ?and how ?? And if someone is expert in those things please tell me because I have some other question and big thanks in advance .

Comment: I think this is more specific and short . And just with one question , the other has other question and thanks

Comment: why are you asking this question again? .... what does it have to do with robotics?

Comment: people do not wear VR headsets while driving cars, so a VR wall would not be visible to drivers

Comment: Hi Belkis, yes it's more direct than the other one, but it still a duplicate you should keep one entry per question you have. and you should refrain from asking unbounded questions.  Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Concerning the matter of your question, this site is not suppose to replace startup engineering team ... And the system you describe would definitely not fit my definition of robotics, I will grant you embedded system or augmented reality keywords. Lastly from an energetic point of view you will need crazi big batteries to achieve what you propose.

Comment: Why big batteries ?? The blind is not going to use it that much ? !

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* belkis, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: You're asking, in this question and the other, "is it doable? and how??" Yes, it's doable - go look at the devices that *already exist* to make laser light shows. You should probably instead be asking yourself if that's the best, most economical solution. Why not use railroad crossing gates? Do you have a budget? How are you going to power this? As @jsotola mentioned in the previous question, light has to *reflect* on *something* in order to be seen, so you'll need a fog machine, too. *Does the fog machine make it harder for vehicles to see pedestrians that can't trigger your effect?*

Comment: Hopefully you can begin to see that there are a bunch of options, a bunch of details you haven't mentioned (cost, size, power, weight, required time table, etc.), that will make this *open-ended design question* turn into a back-and-forth **discussion** instead of being an answerable *question*. Discussions are great, but the Stack Exchange site is not the place for discussions. If you would like to have a discussion here, you can always join us in [chat] when you have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen your previous question about projecting lights on the street using lasers. Well I guess its possible if you are willing to use holographic image projectors. 
And incase of virtual reality you can create identical environment of the real world and add walls where it's necessary, google 360 image has all the pictures of our surrounding, their technology is capable of producing identical virtual world for the (NIGHT ) blind people who cant see in low light.

And I have thought about moving objects , specially transports, cars, buses, etc. The augmented world you will create will have  gps that tracks cars, if not possible for all the car, the driver whose carrying or the passengers have cell phones which has GPS in it can notify the blind people about the moving object because the gps in always working.

It's just a concept, you cant build a project with your own hands but if you are participating in any competition you use this concept by developing this core concept. I Hope it helps. Thanks IN ADVANCE ! and the answer is yes. Possible

Comment: 1st question : What do you mean by adding walls ?? The blind will use the stick in the real world , so what is the benefit of adding walls in identical world ?

Comment: 2nd : We are not totally sure if all drivers have a gps or even a cell phone (in some cases) , so I think we can't guarantee this. And if we do ,how do blind people will know when to cross ? I mean what if we have a big traffic jam in the street ?! so we need something to warm drivers that they have to give the opportunity to the blind .

Comment: Do gps work offline ?

Comment: Try to forgive me about my too much questions and my misunderstanding 